# Use of undeclared Identifier 'Fabric'

Tags: ios, twitter

I'm integrating Twitter Fabric into my app. I get an error when I try to use Fabric to save my keys in my Info.plist. Any ideas? On the documentation it says:

> To initialize the Twitter Kit with your app’s credentials, pass them to `startWithConsumerKey:consumerSecret:` before passing the shared instance to Fabric.
>
> Calling `startWithConsumerKey:consumerSecret:` will override any keys which were automatically configured. Automatically configured keys live in your app’s Info.plist under the key Fabric.

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] startWithConsumerKey:@"your_key"
                                    consumerSecret:@"your_secret"];
[Fabric with:@[[Twitter sharedInstance]]]; //<--Gettings Use of undeclared Identifier 'Fabric' error
```

Comment: Are you missing a libary perhaps?

Comment: Did you add the proper `#import` to this .m file?

Comment: I already have #import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h> for the .m file. Unless there's another header that I have to import.

Answer (score 3):

The Fabric header, which is the parent framework for all child libraries including TwitterKit, must be included here.

Add:

```
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
```

to your .m file.  Make sure you've added the Fabric framework to your Xcode project as well (which is separate from the TwitterKit framework).